# Control section horizontal spacing without squeezing

Tags: formatting, resume

I'm writing a resume under the [res.cls](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls) resume template. I have the following section to describe my *experiences*:

```latex
\documentclass[margin]{res}  

% Default font is the helvetica postscript font
\usepackage{helvet}

% Increase text height
\textheight=700pt

\begin{document}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND ADDRESS SECTION
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\name{my name}

\begin{resume}

% Modify the format of each position
\begin{format}
\title{l}\employer{r}\\
\dates{l}\location{r}\\
\body\\
\end{format}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{EXPERIENCE}

\employer{my employer}
\location{my location}
\dates{dates}
\title{\textbf{A title that's quite long, like this long}}
\begin{position} \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \item item 3
    \end{itemize}
\end{position}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Compiling it comes out looking like this:
[image: example]

You can see the word "long" is on the second row even though it should stay on the first row. It also forced an additional spacing between "my employer" and "my location". I tried searching through the format that's defined in the [res.cls](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/res.cls) to change the format but I'm not very familiar with LaTex. Is there a simple way to fix this?

---

EDIT:

I'm compiling using:

```
15:16 $ pdflatex -version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
Copyright 2019 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.36; using libpng 1.6.36
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.01
```

---

EDIT:

Adding compiler log via request:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.8.27)  9 SEP 2019 15:30
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.res
(./test.res
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(./res.cls
Document Style `res' <26 Sep 89>.
Document Class: res 2000/05/19 v1.4b Resume class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
No auxiliary output files.

\tabular@text=\toks14
\tabular@head=\toks15
\tabular@tail=\toks16
\@ta=\toks17
\undefined@token=\toks18
\sectionwidth=\dimen103
\sectionskip=\skip43
\resumewidth=\dimen104
\@columnwidth=\dimen105
\c@numberofcolumns=\count88
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty
Package: helvet 2005/04/12 PSNFSS-v9.2a (WaS) 

(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks19
))
No file test.aux.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 16.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+cmr on input line 34.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd
File: omscmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <10> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 34.
 [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 344 strings out of 492609
 4036 string characters out of 6129033
 63270 words of memory out of 5000000
 4336 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4553 words of font info for 17 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 29i,8n,20p,117b,181s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/
local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/l
ocal/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/lo
cal/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/loca
l/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 42404 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 24 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 16 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: No problem, I think someone provided a good solution below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position` environment actually sets a table with equal-width columns (2 in your case). That's just the default way of doing things. You can put your *Experience* `\title` inside a zero-width `\makebox` so it can spread across the first column width without problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}  

% Default font is the helvetica postscript font
\usepackage{helvet}

% Increase text height
\textheight=700pt

\begin{document}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND ADDRESS SECTION
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\name{my name}

\begin{resume}

% Modify the format of each position
\begin{format}
  \title{l}\employer{r}\\
  \dates{l}\location{r}\\
  \body\\
\end{format}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{EXPERIENCE}

\employer{my employer}
\location{my location}
\dates{dates}
\title{\makebox[0pt][l]{\textbf{A title that's quite long, like this long}}}
\begin{position} \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
  \end{itemize}
\end{position}

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```